# Loading multiple Datagridviews to different Tabpages

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabpage

Overview: I am creating an application that allows the user to create a register with multiple columns and pages. The number of pages is dynamic (the user can add as many tabpages as they wish). Each tabpage has one gridview with columns displayed. The columns are defined by the user.
When they create a tabpage or a new column it posts the information to an XML file. on opening the application it reads in the XML to show the sheets (with names) and columns (with names).

Issue: When I run the code below for one tabpage with a gridview it all works (I can see grid view in tabpage). when I run the code for more than one tabpage I can see the tabpages but the gridview doesn't display.

```
    Private Sub UF_DEF_COL_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("C:\Users\geoff.warrington\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project Register\Project Register\Tab_List.xml")
    Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
    Dim node_list As XmlNodeList = root.GetElementsByTagName("Tab")

    Me.SHEET_DEF.TabPages.Remove(Register)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim TB = New TabPage
    Dim Col_Data_Grid As New DataGridView

    For x = 0 To node_list.Count - 2
        Dim No_Cols As Integer = node_list(x).ChildNodes.Count - 1
        Me.SHEET_DEF.TabPages.Add(TB)
        With TB
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 22)
            .Name = node_list(x).FirstChild.InnerText
            .Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(805, 172)
            .TabIndex = x + 1
            .Text = node_list(x).FirstChild.InnerText
            .UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        End With

        Col_Data_Grid = New DataGridView() With { _
        .Name = node_list(x).FirstChild.InnerText,
        .ColumnCount = node_list(x).ChildNodes.Count - 1,
        .Location = New Point(8, 8),
        .Size = New Size(1000, 25),
        .AutoSizeRowsMode = _
           DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders,
        .ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single,
        .CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single,
        .GridColor = Color.Black,
        .RowHeadersVisible = False,
        .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect,
        .MultiSelect = False,
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        .Visible = True}

        For Y = 1 To No_Cols
            Col_Data_Grid.Columns(Y - 1).Name = node_list(x).ChildNodes(Y).InnerText
        Next

        SHEET_DEF.TabPages(x).Controls.Add(Col_Data_Grid)

    Next

End Sub
Friend WithEvents Register As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
Friend WithEvents Col_Sel As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Friend WithEvents ID As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents Col_Data_Grid As DataGridView
```

**EDIT** New code as shown below. This still has the same issue, but I feel that it's closer. where "node_list.count - 2" returns one tabpage and the datagridview is completely visible. When I change it to "node_list.count - 1" I can see two tabpages, but neither tabpage holds a datagridview. I don't understand why it would work for one but not more than one.

```
    Private Sub UF_DEF_COL_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("C:\Users\geoff.warrington\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project Register\Project Register\Tab_List.xml")
    Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
    Dim node_list As XmlNodeList = root.GetElementsByTagName("Tab")

    Me.SHEET_DEF.TabPages.Remove(Register)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim TB As New TabPage

    For x = 0 To node_list.Count - 2
        Dim No_Cols As Integer = node_list(x).ChildNodes.Count - 1
        Me.SHEET_DEF.TabPages.Add(TB)
        With TB
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 22)
            .Name = node_list(x).FirstChild.InnerText
            .Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(805, 172)
            .TabIndex = x + 1
            .Text = node_list(x).FirstChild.InnerText
            .UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        End With

        Dim Col_Data_Grid = New DataGridView()

        With Col_Data_Grid
            .Name = node_list(x).FirstChild.InnerText & "DGV"
            .ColumnCount = node_list(x).ChildNodes.Count - 1
            .Location = New Point(8, 8)
            .Size = New Size(1000, 25)
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = _
               DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = _
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
            .ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single
            .CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single
            .GridColor = Color.Black
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
            .MultiSelect = False
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .Visible = True
        End With

        For Y = 1 To No_Cols
            Col_Data_Grid.Columns(Y - 1).Name = node_list(x).ChildNodes(Y).InnerText
        Next

        Col_Data_Grid.Parent = Me.SHEET_DEF.TabPages(x)
        Me.SHEET_DEF.TabPages(x).Controls.Add(Me.Col_Data_Grid)

    Next

End Sub
Friend WithEvents Register As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
Friend WithEvents Col_Sel As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Friend WithEvents ID As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents Col_Data_Grid As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
End Class
```

Comment: I have found the result. A subtle change! Move Dim TB as new TabPage to within the 'for loop' and add the parenthesis afterwards. I can't believe it was that simple!

Link = http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/293990/Unable-to-load-datagridview-to-more-than-1-tabpage/?p=1#Replies

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments the solution was to move the = new tabpage to the loop area and also add the parenthesis.

http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/293990/Unable-to-load-datagridview-to-more-than-1-tabpage/?p=1#Replies